# How to get multiple files from the server using ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get multiple html log files from the server and process them..

Log1.html
Log2.html
Log3.html
Log4.html
Log5.html

```
      $(".selection").change()
      {
          if($.trim($(this).val()) == "Logs")
          {
              // get list of files

              $.getJSON("getFileNames.php",{fileNames: fileNameList}, function(data)
              {
                  $.each(data, function(index,value)
                  {
                       listValues[index] value; 
                  });
              });
              for(var i = 0; i < listValues.length; i++)
              {
                   getLogFiles(listValues[i]);
              }
          }

          getLogFiles(logName)
          {
              status = null;

              $.ajax({
                        url: logName,
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                           status = $(data).find(".status").text();
                           $getJSON("status.php"), {statusInfo: status});
                        }
             });
          }


      }
```

This works if I send one but going to the entire array (listValues) really slows down FF. Is there a better approach to solve this problem. Example would be great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize this in two different ways:

- Right now, you are doing up to `listValues.length`x2 + 1 requests to your server in one go. You could consider re-writing your PHP to try to condense this down into as few requests as possible, which will mean fewer `XMLHttpRequest` objects being created, which means less overhead. This could be as simple as going for `status.php?logfile[]=file1&logfile[]=file2...`
- You could also simply enable client-side caching. I'm sure you have some data on there that is redundant or cacheable

The following is generic advice. Posting the contents of the various AJAX calls may help your case a bit in terms of specific answers.